# Get a non-expiring, non-secure URL from S3 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

My app uploads an image to S3 and returns the URL of that image. However, it returns a URL like `http://my-client-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/gifs/export_gif_3_1438603398.gif?AWSAccessKeyId=AKILLV5BH1BNAT3D3D3Q&Expires=1438607003&Signature=SBQmnULXR5F5cAtyZgqbFl0%2Bn%2Fk%3D`

How can I get it to return the simple URL that doesn't require access key and signature in the URL? Also, the links expire pretty quickly.

Here is my code:

```
bucket.objects[filename].write(result.to_blob, {:acl=>:public_read})
url = bucket.objects[filename].url_for(:read, :secure => false).to_s
```

Comment: I don't think you can ever get non-authorized urls, since Amazon needs to know who's using their bandwidth, and you need the option of cutting access to any given resource. But there is nothing sensitive in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the S3 SDK? It has a [`#public_url` method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#public_url-instance_method).